# Epoxy for faucet handle

Tags: plumbing, faucet

Is there anything I can use to glue my faucet handle in the kitchen on? The set screw place is stripped out and I don't want to buy a new faucet. I've tried Water Weld and the clear jb weld epoxy and neither lasted a day.

Comment: try Gorilla Glue. When that stuff works, wow... only downside is the way it expands as it cures.

Comment: Have you considered tapping a  larger hole?

Comment: are you certain that you have the correct screw? ... maybe someone lost the original and used a smaller substitute

Comment: Yes, it is the correct set screw. This happened when I replaced the valve inside and I had my son help so I could teach him and he got to aggressive with the set screw and stripped the threads on the handle. I have not tried tapping a larger hole. I don't have a tap and die set, but maybe I can get a cheap one at harbor freight. I'll try the gorilla glue first and if it doesn't work I'll try the new hole. Thank you all very much.

Comment: Sorry for the late Reply so far I have tried Gorilla glue and it usually holds good for a week or so then needs to be reglued. Ultimately I probably will just get a new faucet.